# Which of these these two sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar

1. You must be thinking I am mad.
2. You must think I am mad.

Although, both the sentences don't seem to be wrong and seem to convey the same meaning, I want to know which of the two is correct ?

Comment: You mean 'neither of the sentences seems to be wrong', which is true. The difference is that (2) could refer to a person's general opinion of the speaker (they always think he/she is mad), while (1) describes their current state of mind (I'm doing something that seems crazy, so you must be thinking right now that I am mad).

Comment: What @Kate said. Leading to the corollary that one possible difference between ***I think you're mad*** and the far less likely continuous version ***I'm thinking you're mad*** is that the latter can imply ***...but I'm willing to be persuaded otherwise*** (i.e. - my current thinking is inherently ***temporary, liable to change***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean 'neither of the sentences seems to be wrong', which is true. The difference is that (2) could refer to a person's general opinion of the speaker (they always think he/she is mad), while (1) describes their current state of mind (I'm doing something that seems crazy, so you must be thinking right now that I am mad).

Comment: convert answer comment to CW